# Can't read the output of the command when using QProcess

Tags: qprocess

My program needs to send a command line with a QProcess and retrieve the result, which will then be displayed in the GUI.
The command I want to execute and read its output is `ostree remote refs kinoite`
Here is my code:

```
    QProcess* process = new QProcess();

    connect(process,&QProcess::readyReadStandardError,[process]() {
        qWarning()<<"Error: " << process->readAllStandardError();
    });
    
    //catch data output
    connect(process,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,[process]() {
            qWarning()<<"Output: " << process->readAllStandardOutput();
    });

    // delete process instance when done, and get the exit status to handle errors.
    QObject::connect(process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
                     [=](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
        qWarning()<< "process exited with code " << exitCode;
        process->deleteLater();
    });

    process->setWorkingDirectory(QStringLiteral("~"));
    process->start(QStringLiteral("ostree"), {QStringLiteral("remote"), QStringLiteral("refs"), QStringLiteral("kinoite")});
```

The signals aren't received, so nothing is displayed on the terminal when using `qWarning()`
Any help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the QProcess, it was because of running QProcess inside a toolbox.